# Q: How to use circuit analysis on a circuit ideal diodes with ideal op-amps

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis

I have been practicing how to analyze op-amps with diodes as I never really learnt them and thought it would be a handy skill to finally learn.

I have been attempting a question on here that I found, but I am getting stuck.

Here's is the schematic

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7jYZs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am doing a case where the diode is off (assuming ideal). Where I need to find the drop of the diode to be < 0, however I have no idea what is the output voltage of the op-amp. Any hints or suggestions will be helpful!

EDIT: I tried doing the negative input and it looks like the diode is both on and off?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHAYEi.png)</sup>

Comment: This unity gain voltage follower only works for positive inputs. Diode drop is irrelevant since the differential input must be 0V

Comment: Ill re-edit the question to a more difficult one then.

Edited.

Comment: Now you have the opposite inverting negative peak detector. But because there is no load to gnd it is less reliable.

Comment: Hint: consider the op-amp is also a non-linear circuit with more than one operating mode.

Comment: Sorry I meant to say ideal op amp as well

Comment: If the voltage at the opamp \$-\$ input is even slightly positive D1 will be off and the \$-\$ input will be the same as \$V_{in}\$.

Comment: In that case, the output might go to \$-\infty\$ when the diode is not conducting. When you include power supplies in your schematic, it implies you want to consider the limitations imposed by those supplies.

Comment: @ThePhoton: Shocking. In a negative sense. Looks like the rails are at 1V and 0V.

Comment: @copper.hat, yes but when I suggested OP should consider that, they told me they want to use an ideal op-amp model.

Comment: Updated the second diagram to reflect my question better.

Comment: @ThePhoton You're right thats a good statement to think about when making these assumptions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In comments you said you want to consider an ideal op-amp model.

For your second diagram, that means the op-amp's inverting input is at +1 V. It isn't at 0 V as you indicated because there's no feedback from the op-amp output to drive it to 0 V.

The node marked "-1V or 1V?" is also at +1 V by using Ohm's law on R3.

The node marked "????" is at \$-\infty\$ V because the ideal op-amp has infinite gain.

What this really means is that an ideal op-amp model is not useful for analyzing this circuit. You should consider a model that includes saturation behavior so that the op-amp output can not be driven outside the power supply rails.

Comment: Yeah you're right, you helped me solve it by saying the output will be driven to -infinity. Essentially the negative feedback is non operative then :) Which is the correct answer